# Getting Gunicorn to run on port 80

Tags: python, http, gunicorn

I built an API with flask. My app does not have any static assets hence there's no reason for me to use nginx.

I wish to run gunicorn on port 80.

I have a "deploy script":

```
mkdir .log 2> /dev/null
DEBUG=0 gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 backend:app --access-logfile .log/access.log --error-logfile .log/general.log
```

I wish to run gunicorn on port 80 with `authbind`. I followed this [guide](https://mutelight.org/authbind) here.

*Note that I am able to run `authbind python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`*

When I try to run `authbind ./deployment.run 80`,

I am seeing the following error:

```
2013-04-25 15:32:55 [24006] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
2013-04-25 15:33:08 [24018] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
2013-04-25 15:33:08 [24018] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-04-25 15:33:09 [24018] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-04-25 15:33:10 [24018] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-04-25 15:33:11 [24018] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-04-25 15:33:12 [24018] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

Any ideas why I am unable to bind gunicorn to port 80?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try putting authbind inside your deployment script, e.g.:

```
mkdir .log 2> /dev/null
DEBUG=0 authbind gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 backend:app --access-logfile .log/access.log --error-logfile .log/general.log
```

Then just run `./deployment.run 80`.

(Also, your script doesn't seem to be using any parameters; perhaps replace `80` in your script with `$1`?)

Comment: As mentioned by Uku, Unix protects ports under 1024 and authbind doesn't let normal users magically bypass that. It must be configured to allow certain kinds of bindings - see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html and http://mutelight.org/authbind.

Answer (score 49):

If you are on a unix-like environment, ports < 1024 (like 80) will require superuser privileges.

Comment: isn't the whole purpose of authbind is to override that?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `authbind` to achieve this.
Install authbind

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
```

Then use auth bind to modify port 80 to make sure that port 80 can be used by non-superusers (aka without superuser privileges). Here are the three commands you can use to achieve this.

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown USER /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

**USER** - can be any user on your system like bhatman or ubuntu or ec2-user.

**NOTE**: just change 80 to any desired port and it will work for any port. Use this responsibly my friend. :)

Now your gunicorn command will look something like this:

```
authbind gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf wsgi:app
```

Just append `authbind` before your gunicorn command

**BONUS**: If you are using some command before the gunicorn  like newrelic etc, then you need to add --deep flag after authbind

```
authbind --deep newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf wsgi:app
```

for more info about authbind checkout its ubuntu manpage: [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/authbind.1.html)

But before running these commands blindly I would suggest you to read the following points.

1. Gunicorn is an appplication server and is not meant to serve the request directly there it is better to use it behind a web server like Nginx or AWS ALB etc.
2. Ports less than 1024 are privileged ports and should not be opened or used just like that, you should have a strong reason to run applications on such ports.

NGINX is not a necessity for gunicorn, you can use any web server. Your architecture should always look something like this.

```
WEB SERVER (NGINX, AWS ALB etc) -> APPLICATION SERVER (Gunicorn, uWsgi etc) -> Application (Flask, Django etc)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if anyone comes here looking how to do this for apache airflow, I ran the above and then to start the webserver: authbind --dep airflow webserver......this allowed me to run an A record to point mydomain-airflow.com to the IP address of the EC2 instance hosting airflow instead of using an ip address each time to visit the web server