# gunicorn not starting on port 80 but starting on port 8000

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn and trying to write the upstart script. I am testing the command in the command line and for port 80 it just gets errors

command

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --workers 3 myapp.wsgi:application
```

log

```
[2016-10-19 02:36:51 +0000] [12752] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-10-19 02:36:51 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-10-19 02:36:52 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-10-19 02:36:53 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-10-19 02:36:54 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-10-19 02:36:55 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2016-10-19 02:36:56 +0000] [12752] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

any ideas why this is not working? Sometimes it works for port 8000.

Comment: Are you running as root (if running on Linux) (non root in general can't bind to < 1024).  is something else (e.g. apache /iis) already running on port 80?

Comment: @Foon no nothing is running on port 80. Now its working if I use sudo. I thought you generally do not want to run a webserver with root.

Comment: I don't know how gunicorn is setup; I typically start apache httpd via root (as in run service httpd start) but httpd will quickly change user to apache (on RHEL/Fedora; Ubuntu/Debian is similar but slightly different) once it's done the privileged port bind

Comment: @Foon gunicorn will run locally then nginx will be a reverse proxy for it.

Comment: @xazb: Then you do not want gunicorn running on port 80!  nginx will be running on port 80.

Comment: If you already have the NginX running that's why Gunicorn can't listen to the same port. Use another port and modify the NginX configuration accordingly.

Comment: I have written detailed anser for this here, without using nginx or any other web server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802211/5687711

Answer (score 5):

You have to use 'sudo' command for this.

`sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --workers 3 myapp.wsgi:application`

Port 80 requires superuser privilege.

Comment: It worked for me. Try with `sudo pip install gunicorn`.

Comment: You can Nginx as a reverse proxy to Gunicorns' port. For prod this is best.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a unix-like environment, ports < 1024 (like 80) will require superuser privileges.

From the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16225928/6823310

Originally answered by:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/358328/uku-loskit

This is why port 8000 works and 80 do not.

Try running the command with sudo.

Otherwise check if that port is not already being used by another service.